# Simple general rayCasting in box2d Javascript example

Tags: javascript, callback, box2d, raycasting

I've been looking through various tutorials on rayCasting with Box2D, but I haven't seen any clear examples. I was hoping someone familiar with box2dweb would be able to give a clear example of how one would go about setting up a simple function that would end up looking something like this:

```
var myRayCastFunction = function(p1,p2,maxFraction){
    //Code here
}
```

The idea being that it would be usable like this:

```
var retVal = myRayCastFunction(p1,p2,maxFraction)
var fixture = retVal.fixture
var point = retVal.point
var normal = retVal.normal
var fraction = retVal.fraction
```

(in this case, I'm simply returning 1 intersection, say the nearest one, but would want to know how to make a similar one where `retVel` is a list of these outputs for each intersection)

I've been trying to understand all of the details of how RayCasting works in box2D, and I understand that this requires making a custom callback function (I think?), but I never figured out where that function needs to be placed, and what IT should be as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to answer this question because I happened to be about to add raycasting to my current project, and I realized there were actually some bugs in box2dweb that needed to be fixed before I could get it done. I'll link to the details instead of cluttering up this post:
http://www.iforce2d.net/box2dweb-fixes.txt

Here is how I've used the raycast callback successfully. Declare your callback class and give it a ReportFixture function:

```
var RaycastCallback = function() {
    this.m_hit = false;
}
RaycastCallback.prototype.ReportFixture = function(fixture,point,normal,fraction) {

    if ( ... not interested in this fixture ... ) 
        return -1;

    this.m_hit = true;
    this.m_point = point;
    this.m_normal = normal;
    return fraction;
};
```

Now make an instance of that to pass to the worlds RayCast function:

```
var rayStart = ...;
var rayEnd = ...;

var callback = new RaycastCallback();

world.RayCast(callback, rayStart, rayEnd);
if ( callback.m_hit ) {
    ... use callback.m_point etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just have a couple of questions:
1. Could you elaborate the `... not interested in this fixture...` part? I'm not sure what goes there.
2. Where would that `RaycastCallback` code be put?  right now I'm putting it in the box2d/dynamics/b2World.js file, is that right / Does it matter? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Whatever you want. For example, if you want to ignore sensor fixtures, you would use "if ( fixture.IsSensor() )". 2. If it works there, I don't see why it's a problem :)

Comment: Sorry to come back to this question later, but it seems as though my method isn't working quite right. Apparently my test cases from earlier weren't complete. How can I ensure that the callback function is returning the nearest object and point? Testing is a bit difficult, since I think it's non-deterministic which object is being returned. Sometimes I am getting the nearest points, and sometimes I'm not. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Read the section on "Ray casts" in the manual: http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082976 or see the testbed example: https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Testbed/Tests/RayCast.h or this tutorial: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/world-querying